# SQL is taking very long time to run

Tags: sql, time, delayed-execution

When i try to fetch the data from 2 tables Pipeline and Address, whole code freezes and never come back. Data from above mentioned tables are not related to any column present on the tables.

```
with Pronum_tab AS
(

 select  
CONCAT(ouk_shipment.pipeline_ref_id,'A') AS Pronum, AMT1,AMT2 ,AMT3 ,AMT4 ,AMT5,AMT6 ,AMT7,

 case when TO_CHAR(AMT1) is not null then '400' else null END AS CODE1,

 case when TO_CHAR(AMT2) is not null  then '405' else null END  AS CODE2,

 case when TO_CHAR(AMT3) is not null then 'FAS' ELSE null  end AS CODE3,

 case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT4) IS NOT NULL THEN  'SHB' ELSE null  end AS CODE4,

 case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT5) IS NOT NULL THEN '450' ELSE null  end AS CODE5,

case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT6) IS NOT NULL THEN '310' ELSE null  end AS CODE6,

 case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT7) IS NOT NULL THEN 'HAZ' ELSE null END AS CODE7,

 (AMT1+AMT2+AMT3+AMT4+AMT5+AMT6+AMT7) AS BilledAmt,

 0 AS T1_TaxRate1,T2_TaxRate2,0 AS T3_TaxRate3,T2_TaxRate2 AS T4_TaxRate4,
 TO_CHAR(ouk_shipment.ata,'YYYY-MM-DD') AUXDATE1,


CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code in ('FRTRV','FSCRV','SECURFEERV','SECFEERV','HANRV','INLRV','DRYICERV','DGARV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_currency_code END AS Currency,


CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code in('FCFAD','FCFOAD') THEN pipeline_charges.base_cost_exchange_rate END AS EXCHANGE_RATE,

ouk_shipment.pipeline_ref_id BILL_OF_LADING,

ouk_shipment.ata AS DELDATE,
ouk_shipment.shipper_name AS Shipper,

ouk_shipment.orig_country_code AS OCountryCode,
ouk_shipment.port_loading AS OPortCode,
ouk_shipment.total_actual_weight As Weight,
ouk_shipment.chargeable_weight AS DimWeight,
ouk_shipment.total_volume_weight AS Volume1,
ouk_shipment.num_pieces AS Pieces
 FROM (

SELECT


 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('FRTRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT1,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('FSCRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT2,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code IN ('SECURFEERV','SECFEERV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT3,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('HANRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT4,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('INLRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT5,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('DRYICERV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT6,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('DGARV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT7,

 SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code IN ('FCFAD','FCFOAD') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS T2_TaxRate2




from pipeline_charges,ouk_shipment


where pipeline_charges.ppc_ind='C'

and pipeline_charges.import_export_ind IN ('E')

and pipeline_charges.pipeline_tx_id=ouk_shipment.pipeline_tx_id

and pipeline_charges.charge_code in ('FRTRV','FSCRV','SECURFEERV','SECFEERV','HANRV','INLRV','DRYICERV','DGARV')

AND (ouk_shipment.ata BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')

                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))




                                ), ouk_shipment,pipeline_charges

where pipeline_charges.ppc_ind='C'

and pipeline_charges.import_export_ind IN ('E')

and pipeline_charges.pipeline_tx_id=ouk_shipment.pipeline_tx_id

--and pipeline_charges.charge_code in ('FRTRV','FSCRV','SECURFEERV','SECFEERV','HANRV','INLRV','DRYICERV','DGARV')

AND (ouk_shipment.ata BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')

                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))








                                UNION





select   

CONCAT(ouk_shipment.pipeline_ref_id,'B') AS Pronum,AMT1,AMT2 ,AMT3 ,AMT4 ,AMT5,AMT6 ,AMT7,

 case when TO_CHAR(AMT1) is not null then '362' else null END AS CODE1,

 case when TO_CHAR(AMT2) is not null  then '750' else null END  AS CODE2,

 case when TO_CHAR(AMT3) is not null then null ELSE null  end AS CODE3,

 case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT4) IS NOT NULL THEN  null  ELSE null  end AS CODE4,

 case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT5) IS NOT NULL THEN null ELSE null  end AS CODE5,

case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT6) IS NULL THEN null ELSE null  end AS CODE6,

 case WHEN TO_CHAR(AMT7) IS NULL THEN null ELSE null END AS CODE7,

 (AMT1+AMT2+AMT3+AMT4+AMT5+AMT6+AMT7) AS BilledAmt,

 AMT1 AS T1_TaxRate1, 0 as T2_TaxRate2, AMT2 AS T3_TaxRate3, (AMT1+AMT2) AS T4_TaxRate4,
 TO_CHAR(ouk_shipment.ata,'YYYY-MM-DD') AUXDATE1,


CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code in ('HANRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_currency_code END AS Currency,


Null AS EXCHANGE_RATE,

ouk_shipment.pipeline_ref_id BILL_OF_LADING,

ouk_shipment.ata AS DELDATE,
ouk_shipment.shipper_name AS Shipper,

ouk_shipment.orig_country_code AS OCountryCode,
ouk_shipment.port_loading AS OPortCode,
ouk_shipment.total_actual_weight As Weight,
ouk_shipment.chargeable_weight AS DimWeight,
ouk_shipment.total_volume_weight AS Volume1,
ouk_shipment.num_pieces AS Pieces
 FROM (

SELECT

Sum(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code=('HANRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END) AS AMT1,

SUM(CASE WHEN pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('HANRV') THEN pipeline_charges.invoice_charge_amt END)*0.1 AS AMT2,

0 AS AMT3,

0 AS AMT4,

0 AS AMT5,

0 AS AMT6,

0 AS AMT7



from pipeline_charges,ouk_shipment


where pipeline_charges.ppc_ind='C'

and pipeline_charges.import_export_ind IN ('I')

and pipeline_charges.pipeline_tx_id=ouk_shipment.pipeline_tx_id

and pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('HANRV')

AND (ouk_shipment.ata BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')

                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))



                                ), ouk_shipment,pipeline_charges

where pipeline_charges.ppc_ind='C'

and pipeline_charges.import_export_ind IN ('I')

and pipeline_charges.pipeline_tx_id=ouk_shipment.pipeline_tx_id
--
--and pipeline_charges.charge_code = ('HANRV')

AND (ouk_shipment.ata BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')

                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))





    )

    Select distinct 'K550' AS Scac,'5301' AS CUSTNO,BILL_OF_LADING,Pronum,'' AS MB_MasterBol,DELDATE,Shipper,'' AS Oaddr1,'' AS Ocity,'' AS OstateProvience,OCountryCode,OPortCode,
'' AS L1_OriginRegion,'BD KOREA' AS Consignee,'' AS Daddr1,'SEOUL'AS Dcity,'' AS DstateProvience,'22383' AS Dpostcode,
'KR' AS DcountryCode,'ICN' AS DPortCode,'' AS L2_DestinationRegion,'' AS SvcLevel,Weight,DimWeight,'KG' AS WeightUom,Volume1,'X' As VolumeUom,'PLT' as PackageType,Pieces,'' AS SecondaryCarrier,'1002294' AS BillToNum,'A' as Mode1, CODE1,AMT1,'' AS RateQualifier1,'' AS AuditAux1,'' AS RateValue1,CODE2,AMT2 ,'' AS RateQualifier2,'' AS AuditAux2,'' AS RateValue2,
CODE3,AMT3 ,'' AS RateQualifier3,'' AS AuditAux3,'' AS RateValue3,CODE4,AMT4 ,'' AS RateQualifier4,'' AS AuditAux4,'' AS RateValue4,
CODE5,AMT5,'' AS RateQualifier5,'' AS AuditAux5,'' AS RateValue5,CODE6,AMT6 ,'' AS RateQualifier6,'' AS AuditAux6,'' AS RateValue6,
CODE7,AMT7,'' AS RateQualifier7,'' AS AuditAux7,'' AS RateValue7,Currency,BilledAmt,EXCHANGE_RATE,AUXDATE1,T1_TaxRate1,T2_TaxRate2,T3_TaxRate3,T4_TaxRate4,
'KRW' AS Currency2,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum2,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum3,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum4,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum5,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum6,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum7,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum8,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum9,
'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum10,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum11,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum12,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum13,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum14,'' AS CR_ShipperRefNum15,'105-81-76726' AS VX_TaxRegistration
 from pronum_tab

 Order by DELDATE;
```

When i try to add the below sql to extract the data using subquery or directly put it under first Select clause and second Select clause. report freezes and never come back.

select a.postal_code, pipeline.pipeline_tx_date
from address a, pipeline
where a.address_no=ouk_shipment.shipper_address_no

this is just a lookup info.

Please suggest

Comment: Do u mean by adding the script in Subquery, adding where clause ?

Comment: That last query doesn't join those 2 tables on something.  Try to avoid cartesian joins.

Comment: Yes, i want to add "select a.postal_code, pipeline.pipeline_tx_date from address a, pipeline where a.address_no=ouk_shipment.shipper_address_no". I tries adding under where clause in the last where but it's working